# Permissions to protect file from being deleted or modified

Tags: file, shell, permissions, chmod

I want to chmod a directory to prevent any files inside that directory from being deleted or modified without my permission.

How can I achieve that, my directory is set to 777 now which I think is a issue. Could other users access and delete my file without permission if I set the permissions to 777? What permission should I set so that?

I want to be the only one who can write to my own directory, others should only be able to read my file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with `777`, anybody could delete files from the directory.

You should run `chmod 0755 yourdir` or `chmod og-w yourdir`.

- You can see the contents (read), add or remove files (write) and "pass through" the folder (execute)
- Members of the owning group and other users can see the contents of the folder (read) and "pass through" to child folders (execute). They cannot add or remote files (write).

[This guide](http://www.hackinglinuxexposed.com/articles/20030424.html) is a good discussion of *nix directory permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than thinking about it in terms of numeric codes, perhaps it's easier to use the symbolic names for permissions.  For example, to remove the ability for "others" to "write" your files:

```
chmod o-w FILE...
```

You may also want `g-w` if you do not want members of your Unix group to write your files.

The removal of write (w) permissions is the same as "clearing bit 2" in the mode, so 7 becomes 5, but this is hard for most normal people to remember, and you don't entirely need to.